# Why do I get "Require" and "Ensure" instead of "input" and "output" phrases in my pseudocode in IEEE Access format?

Tags: input, pseudocode, output, algpseudocode, ieeeaccess

When I wrote the following pseudocode in \documentclass{article} format, I get "Input" and "Output" phrases after the compilation but when I write the same latex code in the IEEE Access template I get "Require"  and "Ensure" statements as it is, after the compilation. I think in the first case the article format somehow converts the "Require"  and "Ensure" phrases into  "Input" and "Output"  but in IEEE Access format this conversion is not done.

Can someone please explain to me how can I fix this problem? I would like to see "Input" and "Output"  instead of "Require"  and "Ensure" after the compilation.

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{algorithmicx}
 \algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]    
    \caption{Algorithm 1}\label{Alg-Decap}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require{$(C,S_k)$}
        \Ensure{ HashSession$(1,\underbar r,C)$ or HashSession$(0,\rho,C))$ }
        \State $c\leftarrow$ Decode$(\underbar c)$  
        \State $c.(3f)\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $e\leftarrow $ (Rounded$(c.(3f))$ mod 3) $\in \mathcal{R}/3$
        \State $e.(1/g)\in\mathcal{R}/3$
        \State $r'\leftarrow$ Lift($e.(1/g)$) $\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $h.r'\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $c'\leftarrow$ Round$(h.r')$
        \State  $\underbar c'\leftarrow$ Encode$(c')$
        \State $C'\leftarrow(\underbar c',$ HashConfirm$(\underbar r',\underbar h))$
        \If{$C'==C$}
        \State \textbf{return} HashSession$(1,\underbar r,C)$
        \Else
        \State \textbf{ return} HashSession$(0,\rho,C))$
        \EndIf
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I get Require and Ensure also with `article`. There is no way the `article` class is redefining stuff from `algorithmicx`. There is something else going on.

Comment: @campa is this common in research papers to see these phrases " Require" and "Ensure"?  I wonder if it would be oki for a ieeeaccess paper to have " Require" and "Ensure" phrases in the pseudocode? This is my first paper so I am a bit unexperienced in this issue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can map "Require" to "Input" and "Ensure" to "Output" using following settings:

```
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}
```

So in your case, the complete code would be:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[section]{placeins}
\usepackage{algorithm}
 \usepackage{algpseudocode}
 \usepackage{algorithmicx}
 \algdef{SE}[DOWHILE]{Do}{doWhile}{\algorithmicdo}[1]{\algorithmicwhile\ #1}%

\algrenewcommand\algorithmicrequire{\textbf{Input:}}
\algrenewcommand\algorithmicensure{\textbf{Output:}}

\begin{document}
\begin{algorithm}[H]    
    \caption{Algorithm 1}\label{Alg-Decap}
    \begin{algorithmic}[1]
        \Require{$(C,S_k)$}
        \Ensure{ HashSession$(1,\underbar r,C)$ or HashSession$(0,\rho,C))$ }
        \State $c\leftarrow$ Decode$(\underbar c)$  
        \State $c.(3f)\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $e\leftarrow $ (Rounded$(c.(3f))$ mod 3) $\in \mathcal{R}/3$
        \State $e.(1/g)\in\mathcal{R}/3$
        \State $r'\leftarrow$ Lift($e.(1/g)$) $\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $h.r'\in\mathcal{R}/q$
        \State $c'\leftarrow$ Round$(h.r')$
        \State  $\underbar c'\leftarrow$ Encode$(c')$
        \State $C'\leftarrow(\underbar c',$ HashConfirm$(\underbar r',\underbar h))$
        \If{$C'==C$}
        \State \textbf{return} HashSession$(1,\underbar r,C)$
        \Else
        \State \textbf{ return} HashSession$(0,\rho,C))$
        \EndIf
    \end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of changing Require, Ensure to Input, Output]

Comment: does anybody know why the words are changed, though?